# "Lay it on". Would my guess be correct? British English

Tags: slang

Ahm, I liked and quite often listen to [**this old song.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ri3kU7nZN-g&list=FLDUi4OEEh1WnwTT5CYPbE-Q&index=73)

But I haven't paid enough attention to what the singer is singing up until now.

Now, I have a question. The singer says,

From 0:50:

> Oh yeah I'm gonna be a big star, I'm gonna **lay it on** and go "woo-ha"

Would this, "lay it on" fall under the definition of [**this page**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lay%20it%20on)

> informal
>   : to speak in a way that is exaggerated and not sincere

But I'm wondering if this definition really fits with the line of the lyric.

I appreciate if someone can verify or give me an advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Hellloooo....are there any kind British or native speakers here?^^

Comment: Calm down!   It is 7am in Britain now. Let us have our tea first.

Answer (score 1):

First "lyrics warning".  In songs, people say all kinds of things that often don't make much sense, and aren't how people speak conversationally.

It seems he is rapping about "the kung-fu fighter at the disco", later he raps about how he will go to the girl, "lay it on" and take her to the dance floor. He seems to mean "boasting", and getting something by a combination of smart words and smart moves. So the sense of "exaggerated language" fits.

But a noted, its lyrics so meanings so he might just like the sound of "lay it *on* and go Whoo haa".

He is probably referencing the *Saturday Night Fever*, as he talks about the "kung-fu fighter in a white suit" and other 1970s disco or kung-fu movies.

Comment: Thanks！ Sorry for urging you. I sort of understood probably...